# Split the single JSON to multiple JSON based on category but not getting all categories

Tags: python, json

I am trying to generate multiple JSON file based on the categories. I can able to achieve it but however it is not getting all categories.

From the below JSON -> the output file should contain merchant -> 1 record and food - 2 but I am getting only 1 for put. I think it is not looping through to getting all.

input file: pls put the json into a input.json

```
    [
       {
          "requestId":"1",
          "lob":"merchant",
          "event_name":"merchant_page",
          "merchant_name":"Indulge"
    
       },
       {
          "requestId":"2",
          "lob":"food",
          "event_name":"food_page",
          "product_name":"KFC"
    
       },
       {
          "requestId":"3",
          "lob":"food",
          "event_name":"food_page",
          "product_name":"MCD"
       }
    ]
```

the python code which i am trying is below:

```
import json
in_file_path='input.json' # Change me!
with open(in_file_path,'r') as in_json_file:

    # Read the file and convert it to a dictionary
    json_obj_list = json.load(in_json_file)
    #print(json_obj_list)

    for json_obj in json_obj_list:
        filename=json_obj['event_name']+'.json'

        with open(filename, 'w') as out_json_file:
            # Save each obj to their respective filepath
            # with pretty formatting thanks to `indent=4`
            json.dump(json_obj, out_json_file, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating filenames based on event_name which I can see are duplicate two times.

You can make the name of file unique by combining any other field with name.

check below example:

```
filename="%s_%s.json"%(json_obj['event_name'],json_obj['requestId'])
```

Comment: yes that is working but what i am looking for is event="food" i need one file with two records.